# What is a slope of a line?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

What is a slope of a line? I understand that it is obtained by tan$\theta$ where $\theta$ is the inclination of the line but overall what does it means?

Comment: It means the gradient of the line, the change in $y$ divided by the change in $x$

Comment: I don't understand the question. In simple words, slope is the measure of how much the line is tilted in our chosen coordinate system

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope

Comment: See e.g the [Slope or a road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_(slope)).

Answer (score 0):

We can define slope of a line as following $$\text{slope of a straight line}\triangleq\\\text{The amount of vertical increment for any unit amount of horizontal increment}\\={\text{The amount of vertical increment}\over \text{The amount of horizontal increment}}$$which exactly suits the concept of tangent of an angle. Moreover, you can define the slope of tangent on a function is a specific point (provided there exists such a tangent at all for which we call the function **differentiable at $x_0$**) as $$\text{Slope of tangent on a function is point }x_0\triangleq\\{\text{Infinitely small vertical increment around }x_0\over \text{Infinitely small horizontal increment around }x_0}$$